# Write a query to show the distribution of customers by the number of products they have purchased

Tags: sql

Write a query to show the distribution of customers by the number of products they have purchased.

Customer Transaction Table – CUSTOMER_TXNS

```
Column Name Description                              Type

Account_id  Account identifier                      Integer
Txn_timestamp   Time of transaction (UTC)               Timestamp
Product_id  The id of the product purchased             Integer
Txn_Amt         The revenue amount of the transaction       Float
Txn_Qty The number of items purchased                       Integer
```

NOTE: Customer Transaction table has multiple records per account_id.

```
Customer Master Table – CUSTOMER_MSTR

Column Name         Description                        Type
Account_id          Account identifier                 Integer
Country Country         Code                                   Character(3)
Address                 Address of the customer                Character(64)
Registerd_Dt            Date the account id was first used     Date
Tier                    Account Tier                           Integer
```

NOTE: Customer Master table has one record per account_id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select cnt, count(*), min(account_id), max(account_id)
from (select account_id, count(*) as cnt
      from customer_txns
      group by account_id
     ) a
group by cnt
order by cnt;
```

When I run this type of query, I like to have example accounts for each count.

Comment: Gordon, close your parenthesis on the `MIN` function. :-)